# the display of ECDF in R

Tags: r, ecdf

I would like to display a few CDF data (the R code is below), by using a set of numerical BREAKS on a X axis to be shown at EQUAL DISTANCE from each other (although numerically, the BREAKS are on log10 axis and do not reflecting an equal distance):

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(rnorm(100, 0, 3), rnorm(100, 0, 10)),
  g = gl(2, 100)
)

breaks=c(0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 100)

ggplot(df, aes(x, colour = g)) + 
stat_ecdf()  + 
scale_x_log10(breaks=breaks),
```

How shall I do it?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, i've used the following R code :

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, colour = g)) + stat_ecdf() +   
scale_x_log10(breaks=breaks, limits=c(0.001, 1000)) +  
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, angle=45)) + 
labs(title="", y ="", x="PR") +
theme_classic()
```